# WPF datagrid - enable selecting, disabling text input

Tags: wpf, datagrid, edit, datagridcell

I have a C# WPF Datagrid, with a checkbox column, hyperlink columns and text columns.
My DataGrid is bound to a DataTable. The columns are not auto generated, but I do create them in code dynamically, since the number of columns is not known in advance.
I would like to enable the text in the cells to be selected (for ctrl+c purpose) but yet disable editing. I don't want the text to be changed.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is probably be to use a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding YourProperty,Mode=OneWay}"/>                            
        </DataTemplate>                        
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This works also with Checkboxes, add a CheckBox, Bind its IsChecked and use as the content a TextBox that is set to IsReadOnly.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YourBooleanValue}">
                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="YourCopyableTextOrABindingToText"/>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If you want to have the checkbox readonly, set its Enabled-property to false. However in this case, you have to declare the TextBox not as a child but as a sibling of the CheckBox (use a grid or a StackPanel) for this.

If you want to make data readonly for the whole DataGrid, use:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True">
```

THis is also possible for columns:

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True">
```

If you want to define it per row, you have to use `DataGridTemplateColumn`s and bind the IsReadOnly-proeprty of the edit-control.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binind YourReadOnlyProperty}" Text="{Binding YourProperty,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>                        
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: My DataGrid is bound to a DataTable, I create the DataTable and the columns in the code, since the number of columns is known only in runtime. Is there a way to define new datagridtemplatecolumns this way, but dynamically?

Comment: @Yoni: One possibility is to use XamlReader to build your DataGridTemplateColumns on the fly (by string concatenation) and add them then to the columns collection. It looks not very nice but I remember that I have done this also in a similar situation and it worked fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663033.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your users usually copy an entire cell at once you can set the DataGrid's `SelectionUnit` to Cell

If they copy sections of a cell you're better off overwriting the CellTemplate to display a Label as HCL recommended

Answer (score -2):

I'm fairly sure that if you set the DataGridTextBoxColumn's IsReadOnly property to true, you'll still be able to select and copy the contents.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not true.